# EF Core does not update based on the relation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an issue with EF Core general behavior for updating a model. I have the following model classes:

```
public class Province
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int? ProvinceId { get; set; }
     public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
}
```

When I fetch a `City` to edit in the UI, I include `Province` so the UI can show the model perfectly. Now the user wants to change the `Province` for a `City`.

When the user alters the `Province` dropdownlist, the `ProvinceId` of the `City` model will be changed, but the `Province` object is still the same.

So when I send the model to the backend, EF Core does not update the model.

Example - original model :

```
City: { Id: 1, Name: "City1", ProvinceId: 1, Province: { Id: 1, Name: "Province1" } }
```

Altered model in UI:

```
City: {Id: 1, Name: "City1", ProvinceId: 2, Province: { Id: 1, Name: "Province1" } }
```

I expected EF Core to update the the `ProvinceId` to **2** but it doesn't because the `Province` property is still the old one and unless I set the `Province` property to `null` the changes would not be applied properly.

Is there any way to change this behavior of EF Core so it will update the model based on the relation property?

I'm using EF Core 5.0.

Comment: instead of trying to change the rule played by EFCore, I would just follow its rule. Why not you ensure that the reference is null except when it actually contains a ***meaningful*** value?

Comment: BTW, in connected scenarios (such as for desktop app), usually what we change is in the reference (for consistency and convenience as well). But here in a disconnected scenario, I don't think you need to send back the whole reference while just its id is enough. If you follow that pattern, it just works out of the box (because the reference received then is null).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to change this behavior of EF Core so it will update
> the model based on the relation property?

It is already doing exactly that. At model level relations are defined by references/navigations. You sent a related `Province` and EF updated the `City` according to that.

You should notice the inconsistency in the `City` data you are sending - it has `ProvinceId` value 2, but then you have the related `Province` with `Id` 1. When EF updates values for `City` entity at model level (before `SaveChanges`), it sets all the data properties and the value for `ProvinceId` is set to 2. But then, when it sets the `Province` reference, the `ProvinceId` value updated to 1. So That's the value that is sent to database when you call `SaveChanges()`.

To update a parent reference only send the foreign key property, and avoid the reference itself -

```
City: {Id: 1, Name: "City1", ProvinceId: 2 }
```

If that is not possible for any reason, then set the `Province` reference to null before updating the `City`.

Answer (score -1):

May be following reshaped model classes would work for you!

```
public partial class Province
{
    public Province()
    {
        City = new HashSet<City>();            
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> City { get; set; }       
}   

public partial class City
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int? ProvinceId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Province ProvinceNavigation { get; set; }       
}
```